# Storing an array/matrix of ClassificationSVM with fitcsvm() function in Matlab gives me an error, how can I resolve it?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm, multilabel-classification, matrix-storage

I am trying to perform multi-label classification using the SVM libraries in Matlab. There was one solution available for this using the "older" SVM function called svmtrain() [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33170-multi-class-support-vector-machine/). Based on that, I created my own function using fitcsvm().
However, when I try to store the SVM trained model, I get the following error:

> Error using classreg.learning.internal/DisallowVectorOps/subsasgn (line 28)
>
> You cannot assign to an object of class double using () indexing.
>
> Error in multiClassSVM>(parfor body) (line 16)
>
> SVMModel(i) = SVMModelHolder;
>
> Error in multiClassSVM (line 8)
>
> parfor i=1:9

**How can I store multiple ClassificationSVM models in a variable**?

If it helps, the code is given:

```
parfor i=1:9
    label = (labels==i);
    label = i * label;
    disp(size(label));
    disp(size(trainSet));       
    SVMModelHolder = fitcsvm(trainSet, label);
    disp(class(SVMModelHolder))
    SVMModel(i) = SVMModelHolder;
end;
```

I would appreciate any help with this, or any suggestions to do the problem in a completely different way, if that is the way to go.

Comment: I suspect you need to use a cell array for this. Try `SVMModel{i} = SVMModelHolder`, i.e. use curly braces instead of regular parentheses

Comment: Thank you, it worked! But I do not understand why I need to use cell array here. How do I know the difference, and is there any particular documentation I can read about this?
Thanks once again @Dan

Comment: in the docs for the function it tells you what it outputs. The old function output a bunch of different numerical arrays, the new ones output an object. You can't store objects like that in a numerical array, hence you need to use a cell array

Comment: That makes sense... I guess I'll keep learning more and more as I use Matlab further. You have been most helpful @Dan :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fitcsvm` outputs an object which can't be stored in a numerical array and thus you must use a cell array (i.e. curly braces) as follows:

```
SVMModel{i} = SVMModelHolder
```